# Typescript Error: Property 'files' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I wish to create an upload function for my Apps by using IONIC.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<input ion-button block type="file" id="uploadBR">
<input ion-button block type="file" id="uploadIC">
<button ion-button block (click)="upload()">Confirm Claim Restaurant</button>
```

Here is my `upload()` function:

```
upload(){   
   let BR = document.getElementById('uploadBR').files[0]
   let IC = document.getElementById('uploadIC').files[0]
   console.log(BR)
   console.log(IC)    
 }
```

In normal HTML it should work, but it doesn't work with my IONIC.

When building the App, it will show the error `Typescript Error: Property 'files' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.`

Am i do it in wrong way or it has to be done in different way with typescript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You need to cast it as a HTMLInputElement as `files` is a property of `input` element

```
let BR = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('uploadBR')).files[0];
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

In a React.js project you might want to use 'as' to cast because the `<>` syntax does not work in `.tsx` files

```
const file = (document.getElementById(id) as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
```

Comment: you added an answer 5 years later, with a far less elegant answer, to a question which already had a perfect answer?

Comment: Sorry But I was not able to solve my issue with that perfect answer so thought someone might get use of this

Comment: The old answer uses the old casting syntax that does not work in .tsx files. This one works in both .ts and .tsx files. So I'd consider this to be the better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of casting you might want to consider checking that you actually have the correct type:

```
const br = document.getElementById('uploadBR');


if (!(br instanceof HTMLInputElement)) {
    throw new Error("Expected an HTMLInputElement");
}
```

because if you make a typo in the `'uploadBR'` string or change the underlying html you'll get an unhelpful runtime exception because the return value will not be `HTMLInputElement` and TypeScript will be perfectly happy with it because of the casting.

To make it even cleaner you can make an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) for it

```
function assertHTMLInput(el: any): asserts el is HTMLInputElement {
    if (!(el instanceof HTMLInputElement)) {
        throw new Error("Expected to be an input");
    }
}
```

Usage

```
let BR = document.getElementById("uploadBR");
let IC = document.getElementById("uploadIC");
assertHTMLInput(BR);
assertHTMLInput(IC);

// ✅ Properly typed
console.log(BR.files[0]);
console.log(IC.files[0]);
```